# webdev serve doesn't work for basic AngularDart project

Tags: dart, angular-dart

My Dart SDK version is 2.10.1 (installed through Chocolatey)

AngularDart version 6.0.0-alpha (as given by the pubspec.yaml)

I am using Windows

I am using Microsoft Edge for my browser

I use `stagehand` to create my projects

As said above I used `stagehand web-angular` command to create an AngularDart project. It was an empty project which I had not modified after creation. I tried to use the `webdev serve` command in my PowerShell to run my project. I opened the link given in the output but it was taking FOREVER to load. The output was:-

```
[INFO] Building new asset graph completed, took 4.7s
[INFO] Checking for unexpected pre-existing outputs. completed, took 3ms
[INFO] Serving `web` on http://<ip_address here>:8080
[INFO] Generating SDK summary completed, took 8.1s
[INFO] 37.1s elapsed, 499/520 actions completed.
```

The numbers in the last `[INFO]` block started to grow uptil `4532/4800` after which I lost my patience and terminated the command. I have even tried reinstalling Dart but it hasn't worked. It didn't work even when I ran `pub get` and tried to `serve` it again. How to fix this?

Comment: You can try to use the non alpha version of angular, also what is your configuration ? (RAM, processor). What do you mean, you lost patience ? After 1-2 minutes ? 30min, 1h?

Comment: An initial compilation of 2 or 3 minutes is not something strange, it gets better after with DDC refreshing only updated modules (5-10 seconds)

Comment: after 5-10 mins @HadrienLejard

Comment: @HadrienLejard I waited for more time as you said and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try the following pubspec.yaml with your project.

```
name: my_app
description: A web app that uses AngularDart Components
version: 1.0.0

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  angular: ^6.0.0
  angular_components: ^1.0.1
  angular_router: ^2.0.0
  angular_forms: ^3.0.0
  
dev_dependencies:
  angular_test: ^3.0.0
  build_runner: ^1.10.2
  build_test: ^1.2.2
  build_web_compilers: ^2.12.0-dev.3
  #build_web_compilers: ^2.12.2
  test: ^1.15.4
  sass_builder: ^2.1.3
```